# Taking a user defined equation and using it in a VBA sub to calculate numerical values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working on a program to do 4th order Runge Kutta calculations for ordinary differential equations., one of the requirements for the program is that the user will input the equation they want the 4th order operation to calculate. Is there a way to take the user inputted equation from a specific cell and use it in VBA sub to calculate the new y values?
The equations are going to be multi-variable polynomial equations containing x and y.
This is the loop I am hoping to use to perform the calculation, where equa is currently a function with a pre-established equation for testing, but is planned to be the user inputted equation.

```vb
n = (xf - xi) / h

For i = 1 To n
    k1 = equa(x, y)
    y1 = y + k1 * h / 2

    k2 = equa(x + h / 2, y1)
    y2 = y + k2 * h / 2

    k3 = equa(x + h / 2, y2)
    y3 = y + k3 * h / 2

    k4 = equa(x + h, y3)

    yf = y + ((k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4) * (1 / 6) * h)

    Cells(7 + i, 1).Value = y

    x = x + h
Next i
```

Comment: There are many ways. The first to come to mind are using a cell on the sheet or popup a form. You need to decide how you are going to do this before you ask for help. Otherwise, this is a UX design question. Please read this blog post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If the equation is expressed such that it could be used as a worksheet function, you can use Evaluate to produce an output from it.  Your question would get more-useful input if you could expand on what type of formulas you need to handle: examples are always useful.  Not everyone will know what you mean by "RK", so it's best to spell things out.

Comment: It is relatively easy to take a string such `"0.12*x^4*y^3 + 0.3*x*y + 0.17"` and values for `x` and `y` and evaluate it. First substitute values for `x` and `y` and then use `Evaluate`. You could also do something like represent polynomials in `x`, `y` as 2-dimensional matrices, where the first column is the coefficient, the second column the powers of `x` and the third column the powers of `y`. It is easy enough to write a VBA function which will evaluate such a polynomial at a given pair of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example using Evaluate:

```
Debug.Print Resolve("2*<x> + 3*<y>",1,2) '>>8


Function Resolve(sEq As String, x, y)
    Resolve = Application.Evaluate(Replace(Replace(sEq, "<x>", x), "<y>", y))
End Function
```

Comment: That would work. In the past I've run into bugs doing a more naive substitution since e.g. `exp` has an `x` in it (although in OP's case of polynomials it isn't so much an issue).

Comment: Agreed - the `<x>` is intended to minimize that problem, though that's at the expense of making the formula more difficult to input...